# how to measure selectivity for composite index

Tags: oracle, indexing, composite

How to measure selectivity for composite index. 
I know how to measure selectivity of a single column for a index. But if I want to use multiple columns to create composite index, how do I measure the selectivity in order to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by "selectivity for composite index", you mean, how many rows, on average, will be returned when I specify values for Col1, Col2, ... ColN, then you can calculate that with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / SUM(C) FROM 
  (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, ... COLN, COUNT(*) C
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2, ... COLN
  )
```

Comment: I mean the following formula we execute for a single column: selectivity = Distinct Values / Total Number Rows

Comment: Yeah, that's what the query gives - outermost COUNT(*) will give number of distinct combinations of your indexed columns, col1, col2, ... colN, and SUM(C) will be total number of rows in the table.  Dividing the two gives selectivity per your definition.  Not sure if I'm missing something there.